# Fourier serie of $x-\frac{1}{2}$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: fourier-analysis

I must find the Fourier serie of 
$$\phi(x)=x-\frac{1}{2}$$ on $[0,1]$, 
knowing that the Fourier series of $f(x)=x$ is : 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2(-1)^{k+1}\sin(kx)}{k}$$
The solution of this problem is :

> on $[0,1]$, the Fourier coefficient is : 
>   $$a_k=\int_{0}^{1}\phi(x)e^{-2ik\pi x}dx$$
>   and the functions $e^{-2ik\pi x}, k \in Z$ form a orthonormal basis of $L^1([0,1])$. We set $x=2\pi(y-1/2)$, and the Fourier transform of
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2(-1)^{k+1}\sin(k2\pi(y-1/2))}{k}$$
>   Hence the Fourier transform of $\phi$ is : 
>   $$-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2\pi k y)}{\pi k}$$

I don't understand this solution. First, how do we know that the Fourier coefficient $a_k$ is like this ? Then, why do we set a change of variable ? 
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Fouier found out any period signal can be represented by using number of orthogonal signals he derived the above equation from the analogy of vectors and signals.

Comment: sorry I don't understand

Comment: Please refer hear https://www.tutorialspoint.com/signals_and_systems/signals_analysis.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to write the solution in the following way, to lay out the logic more clearly. The Fourier series of $f(x)=x$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ is given by
$$\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} b_ke^{-ikx}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2(-1)^{k+1}\sin(kx)}{k},$$
with
$$b_k=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}xe^{-ikx}dx.$$
Now consider the Fourier series of $x-\frac{1}{2}$ on $[0,1]$, whose Fourier coefficients are
$$\begin{aligned}c_k&=\int_0^1 (y-\frac{1}{2})e^{-2\pi i ky}dy\\
&=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}xe^{-i k(x+\pi)}dx\quad (x=2\pi(y-1/2))\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-ik\pi}b_k.
\end{aligned}$$
Thus the Fourier series of $x-\frac{1}{2}$ on $[0,1]$ is given by
$$\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}c_ke^{-2\pi ikx}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{-ik\pi}b_ke^{-2\pi ikx}.$$
Noting that
$$e^{-ik\pi}=\cos(k\pi)+i\sin(k\pi)=\cos(k\pi)=(-1)^{k+1},$$
the series $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}c_ke^{-2\pi ikx}$ can be simplified to the form in the solution.